# Delete item using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to use LINQ to XML to delete a device element in my file

My file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <IncomingConfig>
    <ip>10.100.101.18</ip>
    <port>5060</port>
  </IncomingConfig>
  <Device>
    <username>xxx</username>
    <password>Pa$$w0rd1</password>
    <domain>go</domain>
    <Uri>xxxx@xxx.com</Uri>
  </Device>
   <Device>
    <username>yyy</username>
    <password>Pa$$w0rd1</password>
    <domain>go</domain>
    <Uri>yyyy@yyyy.com</Uri>
  </Device>

</settings>
```

I'm trying this but it is giving me a `NullReferenceException`

```
public void DeleteDevice(List<Device> devices)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(PATH);

    foreach (Device device in devices)
    {
        doc.Element("Settings").Elements("Device").Where(c => c.Element("URI").Value == device.URI).Remove();
    }
    doc.Save(PATH);
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an exception because of this:

```
c.Element("URI").Value
```

Your `<Device>` elements don't have an element called `<URI>`, so `c.Element("URI")` returns null.

You could change it to:

```
c.Element("Uri").Value
```

but personally I'd change the whole approach:

```
public void DeleteDevice(IEnumerable<Device> devices)
{
    var uris = new HashSet<string>(devices.Select(x => x.URI));
    var doc = XDocument.Load(FULL_PATH);
    doc.Element("settings")
       .Elements("Device")
       .Where(c => uris.Contains((string)c.Element("Uri")))
       .Remove();
    doc.Save(PATH);
}
```

This uses the [`Remove` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx), and by casting to `string` instead of using `.Value`, if there are any elements which don't have `sipUri` child elements, you won't get an exception. (If that represents an error condition anyway, you might want to use `.Value` instead so that you don't continue with invalid data, mind you.)

(I'd also change the `FULL_PATH` and `PATH` identifiers to follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: @tito11 it should work now. Note that the spelling of your XML elements is rather inconsistent, you should choose a convention and stick with it. Jon's code should work with the adjustments I made.

Comment: @tito11: Changing your question so that my answer makes no sense is pretty irritating. (Thanks to @codesparkle for fixing my answer to match the updated question.) What does your *actual* XML contain - `Uri` or `sipUri`?